# How to make fixed div width of parent div, which itself is defined in percentage?

Tags: html, css, width, fixed

I have an issue making a fixed div the width of its parent element, which is itself defined relatively to another div.

It may not be clear at first so here is a code which illustrates the situation:

**HTML**

```
<div class="grandparent">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="fixed"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.grandparent {
     width:100px;
     position:relative;
 }

.parent {
     width:70%;
     position:relative;
 }

.fixed {
     width:100%;
     position:fixed;   /* This div must be fixed and have 100% width relative to parent */
 }
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0vndvzj/#&togetherjs=o1AKKJndhT).

Is there any way the .fixed div can inherit the width of its parent while having a fixed position?

Thank you.

Comment: **You can't**...`position:fixed` is **always** related to the viewport. It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do...perhaps `position:sticky`?

Comment: What is making this need to be a fixed position? As Paulie_D said, that is based on the browser window. You could try to utilize 'absolute' or 'relative' positioning if it needs the position styling. 'Absolute' is relative to its first positioned parent element.

Comment: @Paulie_D I am trying to inherit the parent's width while making it a fixed div. That's why I used `position:fixed`.  Is this impossible?

Comment: @Matthias With pure CSS yes. You'll need javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `postion: absolute` instead of `position: fixed`.

Absolute positionning applies to the first relative parent.
Fixed applies to the window.

You can then place the div relatively to it's parent in the viewport with `top`, `left`, `right`, and `bottom` attributes.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k0vndvzj/3/

Comment: The thing is I would like .fixed to be fixed. Is there any way I can have its position fixed while it inherits the width from its parent?

Comment: It will be totally fixed relatively to its parent. Or if you want more advanced controls, you can use javascript to set a specific width retrieved from any element you desire. see: https://jsfiddle.net/k0vndvzj/4/

Comment: That's a pretty good idea. Unfortunately (I didn't specify) on my website it's about a fixed navigation bar which scrolls down with the page at first (`position:relative`) and then (via js) gets fixed (`position:fixed`) when it reached the top. But thank you, I will do it via javascript as you recommend.

Answer (score -1):

`position: fixed` is relative to window viewport, just remove `position: fixed;` from `.fixed {...}` then you are fine